# React keeping special characters in render

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to render a carousel in react and it is working fine. The issue is with the special characters in the text. The carouselText  contains some special characters are appearing like candidates� instead of candidates'.

```
<div className="servicesslider">
            <Carousel slide={true} controls={false} activeIndex={this.state.index} direction={this.state.direction} onSelect={this.handleSelect}>
              { servicesData.slice(0,5).map((sdata, i) =>
                <Carousel.Item key={i}>
                  <img className="carousel-image" width={557} height={427} alt="first" title="first" src={sdata.carouselImage} />
                  <div className="carousel-body">
                    <h3>{sdata.text}</h3>
                    <p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={ { __html: sdata.carouselText } }></p>                        
                  </div>
                </Carousel.Item>)
              }
            </Carousel>
          </div>
```

Please suggest me a solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

you can send your text as a pure js provided encoding of the JSX file should be **UTF-8**

```
write it as {'your value'}
```

Comment: what is your file encoding?

Comment: try to make your project write files in utf format and then  webpack-encoding-plugin to output files as ISO-8859-1r